# Find duplicate values in input

Tags: java, hashmap, duplicates, hashset

I have an input like:

```
Apple: 0 1
Apple: 4 5
Pear: 0 10
Pear: 11 13
Apple: 5 10
Apple: 2 4
```

And I'm looking for rows, where the fruits are the same and the first value equals to another row's second vale. So I'm looking for rows like: `Apple: 4 5` `Apple: 2 4` and I will also need `Apple: 4 5` `Apple: 5 10`

On the otherhand, I don't want to search the whole data. I mean I don't want to search for `Apple` in `Pears`.

Should I use HashMap? or HashSet? or something else?

Thanks for replies.

Comment: You could create two hashmaps, one for each fruit, and populate the map with the "first" values as the key, and some value (say Boolean). Then for any "second" value for the same fruit, see if it's in the map.

Comment: Alright, I see. But what if I have more than 100 fruits?

Comment: Not a problem for a hash table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try...  It utilizes a `HashMap` of `List`s

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> inputs = new ArrayList<>();
    inputs.add("Apple: 0 1");
    inputs.add("Apple: 4 5");
    inputs.add("Pear: 0 10");
    inputs.add("Pear: 11 13");
    inputs.add("Apple: 5 10");
    inputs.add("Apple: 2 4");

    Map<String, List<Fruit>> fruits = new HashMap<>();
    for (String input : inputs) {
        String[] inputPieces = input.split(" ");
        String name = inputPieces[0].replace(":", "");
        int first = Integer.parseInt(inputPieces[1]);
        int second = Integer.parseInt(inputPieces[2]);

        if (!fruits.containsKey(name)) {
            fruits.put(name, new ArrayList<Fruit>());
        }
        fruits.get(name).add(new Fruit(name, first, second));
    }

    for (String key : fruits.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + ": " + findDuplicates(fruits.get(key)));
    }
}

private static List<Fruit> findDuplicates(List<Fruit> fruits) {
    List<Fruit> results = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < fruits.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < fruits.size(); j++) {
            if (j == i) {
                continue;
            }

            if ((fruits.get(i).first == fruits.get(j).second) ||
                (fruits.get(j).first == fruits.get(i).second)) {
                if (!results.contains(fruits.get(i))){
                    results.add(fruits.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return results;
}

public static class Fruit {
    private String name;
    private int first;
    private int second;

    public Fruit(String name, int first, int second) {
        this.name = name;
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s: %d %d", name, first, second);
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]